# Raspberry Pi 3B+ doesnt play audio via BT speaker

Tags: bluetooth, pi-3b+, speakers

so I wanted to play audio via a bluetooth speaker.
I tried it with my Phillips BTM3160 and my Creative iRoar Go. The Pi wouldn't even connect to the Phillips one and on the Creative it plays with the HDMI output. I've tried Kodi, VLC, omxplayer and mplayer . Every player just plays with the HDMI out. Turning bluetooth off and on again on the pi doesn't help either.

In the file `/boot/config.txt` the line `dtparam=audio=on` is uncommented.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running the `Lite` version of RPi OS - or the `Full` version - or something else? [I've recently learned that the `Lite` version does not include the software for playing music via BT.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116819/bluetooth-blues-redux)

Answer (score 0):

My 3b+ worked straight away. Use the latest clean version of stretch raspbian not just an upgrade (or use rpi-update if you know what your doing). The firmware from 6 months ago has interference between wifi and bluetooth. VLC now works sometimes you have to use the menu to select the correct audio device, kodi doesnt work but can be messed with, chromium-browser works.

From desktop, before you open any app, left click on the bluetooth symbol in the tool bar. Select add device. Put your speaker in pair mode Pair your speaker that pi finds. Right click on the volume icon in tool bar and select your device. I recommend using chromium-browser to check its working.