# Bluetooth Blues, Redux

Tags: audio, bluetooth

### NOTE: All questions here pertain to Raspberry Pi OS, Lite version

I have asked a [similar question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/bluetooth-blues) here, without getting an answer. Eighteen months have passed, new information has come to light and I have a newer version of Raspberry Pi hardware and software. Unfortunately, the results are much the same, but hope springs eternal.

My objective *seems* simple: Play music files on my RPi using the CLI, and listen to that music through a Bluetooth speaker. In the interests of keeping this question as brief as possible, my question will focus on **getting to first base**; i.e. How to establish a solid connection between the RPi and the BT speaker.

It may not be germane to my question, but on another Linux platform (Ubuntu 20.04), it took me about 3-4 minutes to sort this all out from the CLI: discover speaker, pair, connect & play music. That may be an apples-to-oranges comparison, but it seems worth mentioning here.

### A summary of my system:

> Hardware   : BCM2711
> Revision   : b03111
> Firmware   : Jun 15 2020 14:36:19 (see below for further details)
> Model      : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1
> Distro     : Raspberry Pi OS ***Lite***

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi4b 5.4.51-v7l+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:51:40 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux 
...
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ vcgencmd bootloader_version
Jun 15 2020 14:36:19
version c302dea096cc79f102cec12aeeb51abf392bd781 (release)
timestamp 1592228179
...
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ dpkg -l | grep blue
ii  bluez                          5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt2               armhf        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-firmware                 1.2-4+rpt5                          all          Firmware for Bluetooth devices
ii  pi-bluetooth                   0.1.15                              all          Raspberry Pi 3 bluetooth
```

**I have assumed these are all the tools needed by RPi to establish a connection to the speaker. But perhaps this is my first error? Can anyone confirm this?**

### Connection attempts:

Here's what I've tried, and some questions:

#### `hcitool` discovery:

```bsh
$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
    B8:F6:53:12:13:F1   JBL Flip 5
```

Note that after powering the BT speaker up & pressing the BT button on it, I waited several seconds before starting the scan. The scan had to be repeated ~10 times before the BT speaker `JBL Flip 5` was discovered.

#### `bluetoothctl` pairing and connection:

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registration enabled
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

**Note that `bluetoothctl` does not seem to be aware of its own default controller. Some of the references (see below) show the default controller responsive immediately after entering `bluetoothctl`. Other references indicate that `bluetoothctl` must be run w/ `sudo`. It's unclear why this is necessary, but it does make a difference:**

```bsh
$ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# devices
[bluetooth]# list
Controller DC:A6:32:02:F0:97 raspberrypi4b [default]
...
$ bluetoothctl show
Controller DC:A6:32:02:F0:97 (public)
Name: raspberrypi4b
Alias: raspberrypi4b
Class: 0x00000000
Powered: yes
Discoverable: no
Pairable: yes
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: PnP Information (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Access Profile (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0532
Discovering: no
...
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started

...  some time after pressing the BT button on the speaker:

[NEW] Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 JBL Flip 5

[bluetooth]# scan off
Discovery stopped

...

[bluetooth]# info B8:F6:53:12:13:F1
Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 (public)
    Name: JBL Flip 5
    Alias: JBL Flip 5
    Class: 0x00240414
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: no
    Trusted: no
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)

[bluetooth]# pair B8:F6:53:12:13:F1
Attempting to pair with B8:F6:53:12:13:F1
[CHG] Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
```

#### but *immediately* thereafter:

```bsh
[CHG] Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect B8:F6:53:12:13:F1
Attempting to connect to B8:F6:53:12:13:F1
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

**Repeated attempts to restore the connection failed as above. This pattern of a successful pairing & connection, immediately followed by `[CHG]` to `no`/failure has been repeated several times.**

### The Questions:

**1. Why am I unable to maintain a stable BT connection between the RPi and speaker?**

**2. Why does `bluetoothctl` require root privileges to start properly - is this part of the problem?**

### My research:

- [This Q&A seemed very similar](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53408/automatically-connect-trusted-bluetooth-speaker), though I don't need to automate it.
- Several other Q&A and tutorials have been reviewed [1](http://denvycom.com/blog/playing-audio-over-bluetooth-on-rasbperry-pi-command-line/), [2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99975/raspberry-pi-3b-and-beats-pill-bluetooth-speaker), [3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=207025), [4](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/diy-raspberry-pi-bluetooth-speaker), [5](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-bluetooth/), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279646/bluetoothctl-no-default-controller-available), [7](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/how-to-play-sound-and-make-noise-with-your-raspberry-pi/)

**It strikes me that AFAICT no two of the "references" in this collection have anything in common!**

Comment: the Q&A link you provided mentions a `trust` command ... you did not say anything about using "trust"

Comment: Which version of the Raspberry Pi OS are you using? Lite or Desktop? `bluetoothctl` relies on `D-Bus` which doesn't always get started correctly in the lite version. I wrote some notes on connecting to Bluetooth speakers a couple years ago that might have something of interest: https://ukbaz.github.io/howto/Bluetooth_speakers.html  Any tutorial that uses one of the eight deprecated BlueZ tools should probably be avoided (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617)

Comment: @jsotola: I did apply `trust` to the speaker; it doesn't show in this output, but it does in others.

Comment: @ukBaz: I am using the `Lite` version.

Comment: @Seamus: I think that is why you are seeing different results unless you have done extra work to ensure all the services are started. I would suggest running the same experiment in the desktop version (even if you are just ssh-ing) and see if your result is different

Comment: @ukBaz: Looked at your github howto. We have diffs right away (see my edit). In your case, `agent on` gets `Agent registered`, but I get `Agent registration enabled`. No extra work done to start services... I don't have a desktop RPi. Not to seem stubborn, but I feel this should work in `Lite` as well as `Desktop`. Why wouldn't it? Nevertheless - a v. good observation!

Comment: `sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a pi` seems to have helped starting `bluetoothctl`! Unfortunately, immediately after `trust` and `pair`, the speaker immediately falls back to `ServicesResolved: no` and  `Connected: no`  :(

Comment: @Seamus: You are absolutely right, it can work with the lite version. I did manage to get it working once with lite, but then with the next release the recipe to get it to work changed. It was around what packages were installed by default and what systemd services get started by default. I gave up with the lite version. Even though I run headless, I install the desktop version. If you do get it working with lite I would be interested in the recipe to reproduce it. :-)

Comment: @Seamus: After pairing it is normal and expected for it to report `ServicesResolved: no`
    and `Connected: no`. Pairing is exchanging security keys. `connect` is where it should stay connected so that you can play the music.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112899/discussion-between-seamus-and-ukbaz).

Comment: @ukBaz: Please copy his to the [chat session](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112899/discussion-between-seamus-and-ukbaz)

Answer (score 3):

## This is not an answer - it's a sequence of *journal entries*, or just a rambling blog if you prefer!

This doesn't meet SE standards for an answer. Yet, the objective stated in the question above has been met through the steps listed below. I'm posting this as a *"prototype answer"*, which I'll define as a container for information that is useful and pertinent to a proper SE answer. Once a proper SE answer is posted, this material will be moved to my GitHub page. ICYI, further details are posted in [a chat session](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112899/discussion-between-seamus-and-ukbaz) between myself and @ukBaz - who should get credit for the positive result.

### 0. Is Bluetooth Crippled in the *Lite* version Raspbian/RPi OS?

@ukBaz brought this up in the discussion, and now with the benefit of hindsight, it seems clear that he's correct. In addition to the approach outlined below, other "solutions" have been posted that require installation of the `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` package. Early on, I couldn't imagine why a package that's 670 MB - with ~100 dependencies, including several `X` libraries - would be required to play a music file over a BT link. But it seems *RPi OS Lite* must have PulseAudio to enable music-over-Bluetooth! It has been *said* the ALSA package is an alternative to PulseAudio, but that hasn't been demonstrated. **Finally**, it is disappointing that the functional limits of the *RPi OS Lite* distro aren't covered in the [official documentation](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/release_notes.txt). ***Analysis and comments are welcome.***

### 1. Are `root` privileges required to start `bluetoothctl`? (Partial answer)

For reasons that are presently unclear, the `pi` user's **privileges** are different on a *Raspbian Desktop* installation than they are on a *Raspbian Lite* installation! For example, user `pi` on a Desktop RPi system is able to start and control the default Bluetooth controller using `bluetoothctl`, **but not on a Lite RPi system**.

As a solution, some posts online suggest starting `bluetoothctl` with `sudo` (a.k.a. `root` privileges). That may be one way to do it, but other posts suggest that user `pi` be added to the **supplementary group** named `bluetooth`.

You can verify this:

#### 1.1 On Raspbian Desktop, using the CLI:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
Controller DC:A6:32:01:02:03 raspberrypi4b [default]
```

> **The Controller is active & responsive**

#### 1.2 On Raspbian Lite, using the CLI:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# list
No default controller available
```

> **The Controller is non-responsive**

#### 1.3 The Resolution:

Add user `pi` to group `bluetooth`:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a pi
```

Verify:

```bash
getent group | grep bluetooth
bluetooth:x:112:pi
```

Following a `reboot`, user `pi` should find `bluetoothctl` and the Controller responsive without resort to `sudo` privilege elevation. ***Analysis and comments are welcome.***

### 2. Error: `Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed` (Partial Answer)

This error is displayed in the `bluetoothctl` dialog. This error has now been resolved, but will be re-visited in the future. <strike>and is currently ***un-resolved***.</strike> The error is displayed ***after*** the BT Speaker is `trusted` and `paired` with the controller (see command sequence in the Question above). It's a *meaningless* error message in the sense that it provides no clues for troubleshooting.

Based on another useful suggest from @ukBaz, the `btmon` utility was enlisted in an effort to get useful clues for the RPi's failure to make a successful connection to the Bluetooth speaker:

```bash
$ sudo btmon -t

Bluetooth monitor ver 5.50
= Note: Linux version 5.4.51-v7l+ (armv7l)
...

= bluetoothd: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for B8:F6:53:12:13:F1: Protocol not available
```

`btmon` appears to be a useful tool. The system docs are very lean, but the Ubuntu project has a decent [wiki on `btmon` that is helpful](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingBluetooth#How_to_use_btmon_to_capture_an_HCI_trace)

#### 2.1 `a2dp-sink profile connect failed Protocol not available`

Using this error as a search term suggested that the solution involved installation of additional software ([REF 1](https://donjajo.com/bluetooth-fix-a2dp-source-profile-connect-failed-xx-protocol-not-available-linux/), [REF2](https://gist.github.com/actuino/9548329d1bba6663a63886067af5e4cb)). The name of the software is `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`.

Another source, [REF 3](http://denvycom.com/blog/playing-audio-over-bluetooth-on-rasbperry-pi-command-line/) suggested that BlueAlsa was a better alternative to PulseAudio. It appears that PulseAudio may be more widely used, so we'll use it for this pass.

#### 2.2 Install `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`

Following the obligatory `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`, the trusty `apt` was set to the installation of this package:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbus-user-session fontconfig libaom0 libasound2-plugins libasyncns0 libavcodec58 libavresample4 libavutil56 libcairo2 libcodec2-0.8.1 libcroco3

...


0 upgraded, 102 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 46.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 670 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
```

Probably a good idea to `reboot` at this point.

This seems a staggering amount of disk space (670MB) to stream music files over a Bluetooth link. By comparison, `df -H` says the entire *Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Lite* installation occupies a bit less than 1,500 MB. That's quite a lot of **stuff**, and includes numerous dependencies on `X` window libs - whose utility in the `Lite` system is unclear. Nevertheless, we'll proceed with this `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` approach now, but revisit it for a leaner solution.

The Debian project has an overview page for [`pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/pulseaudio-module-bluetooth) that's an easy read.

#### 2.3 Start the `pulseaudio` server

If it's not clear, `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` is a module in the PulseAudio "family". In fact, installing `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` also installed `pulseaudio` as a "dependency".

For those who are interested, the document ['PulseAudio under the hood'](https://gavv.github.io/articles/pulseaudio-under-the-hood/) provides a fairly extensive "introduction" to PulseAudio (TL;DR). The [Debian overview on PulseAudio](https://packages.debian.org/buster/pulseaudio) is brief & to the point. PulseAudio also has a Wikipedia page that's worth reading. One useful bit of trivia from Wikipedia is that the author of PulseAudio ([Lennart Poettering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennart_Poettering)) is also the author of `systemd` and `avahi` :0

At a more mundane level, it's also worth noting that the Debian overview on PulseAudio suggests PulseAudio has undergone major changes since `jessie`. Change is good.

It seems likely that the `pulseaudio` server would be started by `systemd` on those distributions that include it. But that's not the case with `RPiOS Lite`, so we'll do it manually:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ pulseaudio --start
```

#### 2.4 Test for RPi - Bluetooth connection

Before attempting the connection, start `bluetoothctl` to see if the Controller has any additional capabilities that may cause a different outcome:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
Controller DC:A6:32:02:F0:97 raspberrypi4b [default]
[bluetooth]# show
Controller DC:A6:32:02:F0:97 (public)
    Name: raspberrypi4b
    Alias: raspberrypi4b
    Class: 0x000c0000
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: no
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0532
    Discovering: no
...
[bluetooth]# devices
Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 JBL Flip 5
...
[bluetooth]# info B8:F6:53:12:13:F1
Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 (public)
    Name: JBL Flip 5
    Alias: JBL Flip 5
    Class: 0x00240414
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    ManufacturerData Key: 0x0057
    ManufacturerData Value:
  31 1f 01 18 8d 00                                1.....
    ServiceData Key: 0000fddf-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

This looks promising - the Controller (RPi) now has `Audio Source` and a few other capabilities that may be useful. The BT speaker remains `paired` and `trusted`. Let's turn the speaker on & try to connect:

Interestingly, immediately after pushing the power button on the speaker `JBL Flip 5`, it connected without a request (is this `trust` or what? :)

```bash
[CHG] Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 Connected: yes
[JBL Flip 5]# info B8:F6:53:12:13:F1
Device B8:F6:53:12:13:F1 (public)
    Name: JBL Flip 5
    Alias: JBL Flip 5
    Class: 0x00240414
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    ManufacturerData Key: 0x0057
    ManufacturerData Value:
  31 1f 01 18 8d 00                                1.....
    ServiceData Key: 0000fddf-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

And so it seems we have made progress! In the next "chapter" below, we'll attempt to actually stream & play music over the speaker - the final objective for this installment.

#### 2.5 The Resolution:

Install `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` (and all of its dependencies).

```bash
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Other potential solutions will be evaluated in the future. ***Analysis and comments are welcome.***

### 3. Stream & play music from RPi to Bluetooth speaker

With a [little help from my friends, esp @ukBaz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0C58ttB2-Qg), I am now enjoying Dizzy Gillespie's "Night in Tunisia" being streamed from an RPi 4 "Lite" to the Bluetooth speaker on my desk! Here's the ["blow-by-blow"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow-by-blow) account of this final phase of this "answer":

#### 3.1 `mpg321` gives me nothing!

After successfully connecting the Bluetooth stack in PulseAudio on the RPi 4 to a 'JBL Flip 5' speaker, I imagined for a few minutes that I was one step away from [nirvana](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nirvana). It wasn't quite that straightforward:

I wanted a command-line music player that could handle MP3-encoded files, and the [quaint application `mpg321`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpg123) appeared. Install, review `man mpg321`, and run:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ sudo apt install mpg321
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ man mpg321
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ mpg321 -g 50 NightTunisia.mp3 

... (crickets)
```

So - no error messages, but no music either!

#### 3.2 `connect speaker with cable` (aka configure PulseAudio)

And once again, @ukBaz provides the guidance:

> How do you select which output (card) the audio is going to?
>
> Does this help? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Set_the_default_output_sink

Indeed it does! Arch Linux has perhaps the best, most up-to-date documentation on *all things Linux* on the Internet today. The [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Main_page) in particular is a valuable resource! And so, after a couple of tries, it was learned that this is the ***magic spell that connects the speaker wires from the RPi to the Bluetooth speaker :***

```bash
pacmd "set-default-source bluez_sink.B8_F6_53_12_13_F1.a2dp_sink.monitor"
```

Some explanation is in order here as the PulseAudio CLI is incomprehensible to all but the *PA-cognoscenti*. Unfortunately, I am unable to offer a cogent explanation! Here's the best I can do for now:

The PulseAudio concept of **sources** and **sinks** is the first thing that escapes me. While it accomplished the objective, the command `pacmd "set-default-source...` strikes me as *backwards*: The RPi should be the **source**, and the speaker should be the **sink**!

Pondering this, while perusing `man pacmd` and `man pulse-cli-syntax` didn't provide any revelations, but it did lead me to try this:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ pacmd list | grep -e 'index:' -e 'name:'
Default sink name:   bluez_sink.B8_F6_53_12_13_F1.a2dp_sink
Default source name: bluez_sink.B8_F6_53_12_13_F1.a2dp_sink.monitor
...
```

While this doesn't actually *explain* anything, it seems apparent that `source` and `sink` are software abstractions, and need not have any relevance to the physical world. Yeah - that's weak, but it's all I've got for now, and I am rapidly becoming bored with this :)

#### 3.3 The Resolution:

Now that PulseAudio *hopefully* has its inputs and outputs connected properly, it's time to give `mpg321` another try:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ mpg321 -g 50 NightTunisia.mp3
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layer 1, 2, and 3.
Version 0.3.2-1 (2012/03/25). Written and copyrights by Joe Drew,
now maintained by Nanakos Chrysostomos and others.
Uses code from various people. See 'README' for more!
THIS SOFTWARE COMES WITH ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY! USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!
Title   : A Night In Tunisia             Artist : Dizzy Gillespie & Charlie Park
Album   : Town Hall, New York City, June Year    : 2005

Playing MPEG stream from NightTunisia.mp3 ...
MPEG 1.0 layer III, 128 kbit/s, 44100 Hz joint-stereo
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front

[7:34] Decoding of NightTunisia.mp3 finished.
```

It works, and the sound quality is impressive! There are numerous reports scattered around the Internet stating that the RPi audio playback on Bluetooth is scratchy, noisy and unacceptable. To my ears, the playback of "Night in Tunisia" sourced from this RPi 4 sounded at least as good as good as the playback from  my Ubuntu 20.04 system hosted on a 2011 Macbook Pro. Of course that was **5 days ago**, so the setup was a bit longer than the 3-4 minutes required for setup on an Ubuntu Desktop - but who's counting?

### Firmware Epilogue:

I'm posting this as an edit because I recall reading that some have speculated the RPi 4 ***firmware*** may have something to do with the sound quality issues reported for the RPi. When I posted the Question, the firmware was up-to-date. However, I have just checked, and it seems a new revision has been released since this saga began:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ sudo rpi-eeprom-update
BCM2711 detected
Dedicated VL805 EEPROM detected
*** UPDATE AVAILABLE ***
BOOTLOADER: update available
CURRENT: Mon 15 Jun 13:36:19 UTC 2020 (1592228179)
 LATEST: Thu  3 Sep 12:11:43 UTC 2020 (1599135103)
 FW DIR: /lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/critical
VL805: update available
CURRENT: 000137ad
 LATEST: 000138a1
```

Comment: I was unaware you didn't have permissions on Lite, but I have never worried. I setup using the GUI **then** Backup Bluetooth using `sudo su; tar cf bluePi.tar /var/lib/bluetooth` whenever I get a new Pi or Bluetooth device then copy to all my images. (Obviously this does not permit pairing to multiple BT controllers, but permits multiple images to be used in the Pi.) This enables BT on my Lite images.

Comment: @Milliways: That's a potentially useful trick - thanks for sharing. I'm going to keep plugging away on my current course - mostly because I'm stubborn I guess, but also for the "learning experience" as I need to learn more about Bluetooth. If you'll write this up as an answer here (or under another Q if you prefer), I'll up-vote it. I do think it could be very useful for some. I wonder if you could "package" it for d/l? Do you know the size of it? I ask b/c the `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` is near the size of the entire Lite distro!