# Access Denied when scanning for BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) devices

Tags: bluetooth, security, raspberry-pi-os

I'm running an up to date version of Buster on a Pi 3B+ (v1.3) and my Python program dies with

```
txdbus.error.remoteerror:
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message
```

errors unless I run under root (e.g. `sudo python3 myblepgm.py`) at which point it completes fine.

Checking the groups defined in /etc/group, I cannot see an obvious one that 'pi' could join to give access to Bluetooth / BLE devices.

I am loath to run the program long term under root if it's not needed (and would be happy to create a specific user for this), so does anyone know what rights / groups the program and user need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this will help, but:

I found during a [recent exercise](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116819/bluetooth-blues-redux) that user `pi` is not necessarily a member of the BT group. In my case, this was cured as follows:

```bsh
$ sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a pi
```

You may need a `reboot` after making this change.

Comment: Thanks for that - no idea why I missed that group when I listed them!

Comment: @Andyroo, was this on the lite version of the OS?

Comment: @ukBaz A bit of a mix it's the full version (without 'recommended software') but starting in command line mode as it ended up headless.

Comment: @Seamus I used `getent group` as Pi (and `sudo less /etc/group`) but was watching TV and working off my iPad at the time so the screen only has about 10 lines with the keyboard up!  The group is there, I just missed it so was stuck where to start (blush).