# Bluetooth is not connecting

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, pi-400

I'm having trouble connecting my Raspberry Pi 400 to my Bluetooth speaker:

```
GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists: Already Exists
```

Any idea on how to resolve this? The same message pops up for my Bluetooth headphones. I can pair just fine to my laptop though.

Comment: how to resolve what? ... what action are you doing when the error comes up

Comment: This comment is strictly in the FWIW category, but [this rambling discourse](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116819/bluetooth-blues-redux) may help you shake some things loose.

Comment: I've been trying to connect to my Bluetooth speaker and the above error was occurring. I'm able to connect now (not sure why) and I wonder if it might be because I did a "sudo apt update" because I was having trouble viewing "Recommended software" under preferences. I've checked bluetoothctl-->info under device and it shows that it's paired but there's still not audio from VLC media player. It says no next to LegacyPairing. Does this need to be activated? If so, how do I do that?