# No audio device

Tags: audio

I want sound to work but it just doesn't. I have a raspberry pi 3 b and every time I follow raspi-config the system then audio, I go right back to the system.

I don't know what to do and I just got this today. I've used outside help and other sites but it doesn't work. When I right-click the sound button, it says `no audio devices found.`  Also when I try to look at advanced settings, A9 doesn't show up Help? I can't figure out how to connect an audio device.

Comment: i do not understand this stuff at all but im figuring it out as i go. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Bluetooth remains a marginally-supported feature on Raspberry Pi. You didn't mention which version of RPi you're trying to use, but you should know that the last time I checked, part of the problem with the ***Lite*** distro was that user pi was not a member of the `bluetooth` group.

FWIW, my trials and tribulations were documented in [this Q&A from over 2 years go](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116819/bluetooth-blues-redux). If you're using the Lite distro, this might still be of some help.